# C# EF SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Hola lo que quiero hacer es pasar este query de sql a ef, quiero saber si existe un metodo más facil

Tablas

```
CREATE TABLE Linea(
    idLinea INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    NumeroLinea VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE DetalleLinea(
    idDetalleLinea INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    idLinea INT,
    Notas VARCHAR(10)
)
```

Query

```
INSERT INTO Linea(NumeroLinea) VALUES('001')
INSERT INTO DetalleLinea(idLinea, Notas) VALUES(SCOPE_IDENTITY(), '');
```

Ahora mismo lo estoy haciendo así y funciona, pero quiero saber si existe una forma más facil

```
var Linea1 = new Linea(){ NumeroLinea = "001" }
_context.Linea.add(Linea1);
_context.SaveChanges();

var DetalleLinea1 = new DetalleLinea(idLinea = Linea1.idLinea, Notas = "")
_context.DetalleLinea.add(DetalleLinea1);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí. Existe una forma más fácil. No sólo eso, la forma en que o haces ahorita podría causarte problemas. Qué ocurre si se guarda la línea, pero guardar el detalle falla? Tendrás cabeceras sin detalles, y en algunos procesos/sistemas puede no sea aceptable.

Si tienes correctamente configuradas las relaciones en EF, y la clase `Linea` tiene una propiedad

```
public List<DetalleLinea> Detalles { get; set; }
```

puedes agregar el `DetalleLinea` como hijo de la línea:

```
var Linea1 = new Linea() { NumeroLinea = "001" }
var DetalleLinea1 = new DetalleLinea( Notas = "")
Linea1.Detalles.Add(DetalleLinea1);

_context.Linea.add(Linea1); 
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Entity Framework automáticamente inferirá las tablas y las relaciones y correctamente insertará el detalle con el ID de Línea correcto.

Comment: Gracias si jalo con madre :)